# MySQL Need return a count of unique combinations of cols

Tags: mysql

I'm coding a video game and using MySQL to display an icon showing the player where treasure is located.  The database stores the locations by their X and Y on a square map.  I would like to also count the number of items on each square.

So given a table such as this

```
Id   x   y
==  ==  ==
1    2   3
2    3   2
3    3   2
4    4   4
5    4   4
6    4   4
```

I would like to return something to the effect of

```
x y count
= = =====
4 4 3
3 2 2
2 3 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` clause for results.

```
Select x, y, count(*) as 'count' from mytable group by x, y
```

Answer (score 5):

What about concatenate your 2 columns and use DISTINCT ?

```
Select x, y, count(DISTINCT CONCAT(x, '_', y)) as 'count' from mytable group by x, y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x,y,SUM(1) FROM table GROUP BY x,y;
```